# Commad prompt's unusual behaviour. Can anyone explain this?

Tags: cmd

For changing the drive in cmd, we usually write the **drive letter** as follows:

```
E:
```

The drive will be changed to E drive,but the following behaviour of cmd is surpising to me:

```
C:\Users\Rohan>cd E:/java/java files/Applets
C:\Users\Rohan>E:
E:\JAVA\java files\Applets>dir

 Volume in drive E is DISK1_VOL2
 Volume Serial Number is 94AA-4876

  Directory of E:\JAVA\java files\Applets
```

See the way the entire directory path changes, instead of just the drive by giving a cd command, preceding the drive letter.

Can anyone explain, how this happens?

Comment: In Win7 (at least) there is `CD /D` option.  Try `cd /?` on your version of windows.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher  I'm running Win7, and I knew about the **/d** switch, but I needed an explaination, see answer by our friend **Frank**. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher The option `/d` has been there at least since Windows 2000, probably longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as if every drive has its own ***current directory***. So you can change each drive's ***current directory*** separately, but you'll always have one ***active*** drive selected.

If you change to another drive, its ***current directory*** is also made active. If you want a more consistent way of changing the drive and directory in one step, you can use the `CD` command with the `/D` switch. Like this:

```
C:\Users\Rohan>cd /D "E:/java/java files/Applets"
E:\JAVA\java files\Applets>
```

Comment: In earlier versions of MS products, `cd a:\dos` followed by `a:` would have put the user in the `a:\dos` directory.  `cd` behavior changed somewhere along the line.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: But what you describe is exactly what the OP is experiencing. I don't see any difference here between older and current OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, that's always been the case. With the drive letter you switch drive, while with `cd` you set the current directory for just that particular drive.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to change the drive and directory at the same time is to use PUSHD

```
pushd "E:/java/java files/Applets"
```

You can use an undocumented dynamic variable to examine the current directory of any given drive.

```
echo %=c:%
echo %=e:%
```